# Using pssh to replace text in place

Tags: sed, pssh

Anyone here used pssh to modify files in place, I've tried attempts like so;

```
while read line; 
do 
pssh --inline-stdout -H "$line" "hostname;
sudo sed -i \'s/search domain123.local/search domain123.local domain456.local/g\' /etc/resolv.conf;
sleep 1"; 
done < <(cat listOfIPs.txt)
```

Although pssh returns Success status, it doesn't amend resolv.conf on the actual host - am I missing something obvious in the pssh or sed command?

Thanks!

Comment: `-i` is sometimes tricky. Did you try non-inplace and check the output?

Answer (score 0):

I found by altering the quotes, from single to double in the sed part, it seemed to fix it:

```
while read line; 
do 
pssh --inline-stdout -H "$line" "hostname;
sudo sed -i \"s/search domain123.local/search domain123.local domain456.local/\" /etc/resolv.conf;"; 
done < <(cat listOfIPs.txt)
```

And I also removed the `/g` but I don't think that really made a diff